# AngularJS Scope Apply does not working on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm trying to  se scope variable value after on click event using the following code:

```
$('#teamDetailTabs a').click(function(data) {
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    console.log($(this).attr('data-target'));
                    $scope.activeTab = $(this).attr('data-target');
                    console.log($scope.activeTab);
                });
});
```

Problem is that value $scope.activeTab is undefined even if I used $scope.apply.

How can I solve it please?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context (`this`) inside `apply` call is not what you expect, it's no longer `a` DOMElement. So you can fix it like this:

```
var self = this;
$scope.$apply(function() {
    console.log($(self).attr('data-target'));
    $scope.activeTab = $(self).attr('data-target');
    console.log($scope.activeTab);
});
```

**However**, I strongly encourage you to go with `ngClick` and never use jQuery style approach in Angular app. Take a look at this very [detailed thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).